# Seeding with a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to seed my db with recipes that has a has_many relationship with ingredients. The ingredient table has 4 rows. I keep running into errors with my code however. Here's my code. I'm fairly new to rails but could not find a solution yet. I'm using Rails 4 with Postgres.

The Error

```
rake aborted!
Ingredient(#xxxxxxx) expected, got Hash(#xxxxxxx)

Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Recipe

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :descrition, :image
   has_many :ingredients
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end
```

Ingredient

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :measure, :modifier, :item, :note
   belongs_to :recipe
end
```

Seed.rb  (example here has 2 ingredients with content in each row of each ingredient)

```
Recipe.create(
[{
    title: "Recipe title here", 
    description: "This is the description", 
    image: "theimage.jpg", 
    ingredients_attributes: [{measure: "1cup", modifier: "canned", item: "Mushrooms", note: "drained"}, {measure: "1lb", modifier: "sliced", item: "Bacon", note: "previously cooked"},]
}], 
without_protection: true)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
recipe = Recipe.create({
    title: "Recipe title here", 
    description: "This is the description", 
    image: "theimage.jpg"})

recipe.ingredients.create(measure: "1cup", modifier: "canned", item: "Mushrooms", note: "drained")
recipe.ingredients.create(measure: "1lb", modifier: "sliced", item: "Bacon", note: "previously cooked"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix you solution, but I suggest this approach:

```
# initialize new recipe
recipe = Recipe.new(title: "", description: "", image: "")

# build ingredients
recipe.ingredients.build(measure: "", modifier: "", item: "", note: "")
recipe.ingredients.build(measure: "", modifier: "", item: "", note: "")

recipe.save
```

When you run .save on recipe, ingredients will be saved too.